# Math 'glitch' while implementing Digital Compass - Heading Lock

Tags: trigonometry, logic, optimization

Pardon me if I am going toward robotics on this platform. But my problem seems to be **more mathematical**.

I want to implement *Heading Lock* with a digital Compass on my robot. Using a digital Compass, i have  `atan2(Y,X)` which gives me heading from sensor output X,Y.

Now to Control the heading, I programmed the following logic which determines the shortest rotation to reach the heading setpoint. It may not be perfect but it works absolutely fine until there is a change at 0|360°.

To get an intuition what it does : Say the setpoint is 10° and due to some disturbance the heading changed to 20° so it should rotate 10° counter-clockwise. If the disturbance caused the heading to be 340°, the rotation should be 30° clockwise.

```
double GET_HEAD_CORR(double sp,double cp){
  double error = (sp - cp); //"setpoint" & "currentpoint" 
  double x =0;
  
    if(sp < cp){ 
      return  -((error <= 180) ? (-1*error) : sp + (360 - cp));
    }
    else if(sp > cp){
      return ((error <= 180) ? error : (-1 * (cp + (360 - sp))));
    }
}
```

If this algo is not used, the robot will make 340° turn to reach 10° on other side. which is not desired.

So while the algo is running and if the 0|360 point comes, I get a control "spike" as below:
[the control spike](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7YJm.png)

What am I doing wrong ? How to get a smooth control without such spike ? I am sure this is due to the algo I coded but cant figure out the cause.

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what the graph is doing, but you can't avoid the branch crossing to appear somewhere unless you keep also the number of revolutions since the start.  You also have the 180 sudden switch problem in your code that is unfixable.

Comment: Is it "guimbal lock" issue ?

Comment: @JeanMarie No. Actually, in a simple way, there is no smooth transistion from 0-->360 or 360-->0

Comment: @user10354138 The graph is the PID output or you can consider it as *error*